# Grid thumbnail / item size using calc ( )

Tags: php, css, wordpress, thumbnails, image-size

I'm trying to create a full-width responsive portfolio grid. I set the width of the items using calc(), and set the thumbnail image to take up 100% of thumbnail div using:

```
  `img.attachment-portfolio-thumb{
    width:100% !important;
    height:100% !important;
}`
```

This works, aside that there is about an extra white 10 pixels below each image, inside each div.portfolio-list, and I can't figure out where it is coming from and how to get rid of it. In "inspect element", when hover over the div.portfolio-list, the div takes up the entire space 100%, so it's something inside the div which is causing the extra space.
What I noticed is that in "inspect element" mode the `<a>` tag (that the portfolio-thumb thumbnail is in, in the Pods Template), has the following dimensions - and the white extra space if part of it: 315px x 26px (315px is the width of the div.portfolio-list as this browser width).

Link to visual image: The left is on hover, as you can tell the overlay includes the bottom empty 10px. The right bottom you see a white strip.
http://prntscr.com/5yedsp

Below is the code for the grid:

Pods Template:

```
<div class="portfolio-list">
   <div class="overlay">
   <p><a href="{@permalink}">{@post_title}</a></p>
   <a href="{@permalink}">{@post_thumbnail.portfolio-thumb}</a>
   </div>
```

PHP:

```
<section class="portfolio_home_inner">
<section class="portfolio_home">
<?php
    echo do_shortcode ('[pods name="portfolio" template="portfolio-list"]');
?>

/ Add Image size for Portfolio List
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
// additional image sizes
add_image_size('portfolio-thumb', 300, 300, true ); // (cropped)
}
```

CSS:

```
    div .portfolio-list{
    float:left;
    width: calc(20%);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/*Wordpress default selector for new image size*/
    img.attachment-portfolio-thumb{
    width:100% !important;
    height:100% !important;
}

div .portfolio-list p{
    display: none;
    color:#000;
}


div .overlay:hover:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(234,79,38,.85);
}
```

Would anyone know what is causing the extra 10px underneath the image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You image has a margin on it of 32px 0 15px (inspect element with chrome), for the class ".image_pic". Setting the image_pic "margin-bottom : 0;" should sort it out for you, perhaps with the important tag.